# How to get a particular text inside HTML using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How to get the text "Attractions" from the below HTML ?

```
<li class="product">
     <strong>
        <a href="http://[SITENAME]/id=23423">Attractions</a>
    </strong>
    <span></span>
</li>
```

I usually get this done by the below code, when i need the text inside span. But need some help for the above situation.

```
foreach (HtmlNode selectNode in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='cityName']"))
                    {
                        Result = selectNode.InnerHtml;
                    }
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Shouldn't you know how to ask questions?

Answer (score 0):

```
Result = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//li[@class='product']/strong/a").InnerText;
```

You can also do a foreach using SelectNodes like what you did up there.